# Custom per-page sidebar widgets in Wordpress.. possible?

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

Let's say I'm doing a site about cars, and in the main content area there are a few paragraphs about a particular car.

In the sidebar, are several standard widgets. But I also want a widget with an 'info panel' about the particular car.

So what's the sanest way of putting in a per-page widget in Wordpress? I guess ideally the info-panel could be entered via the standard page editing in Wordpress. (or is this something a plug-in already covers?)

Comment: Try asking this on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget Logic plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Answer (score 0):

Another Option would be to download and install the [Graceful Sidebar Widget](http://www.mlynn.org/graceful-sidebar-plugin).  This plugin enables you to create a sidebar that with content specific to each page or post.  You specify the sidebar content right inside the post edit screen.  Hope this helps!

Enjoy!
Mike